# Calling a Stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm new to C# I need to call a SP and return the table value from C#.

I'm passing current `datetime(@currentdate)` as my input parameter in the stored procedure.So how do I pass this in C# method?

Pls help me to write a C# method to call that SP and return the value

I have my sp ready. sp will return the top updated record in the table.

I have used this in my C# code

```
string _Num = null;
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ReferenceDB;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
Int32 rowsAffected;
Object returnValue;

cmd.CommandText = "Number";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CurrentDate", DateTime.Now);
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (returnValue != null)
    _Num = returnValue.ToString();

return _Num
```

Comment: BTW you can use the SQL current date in your query directly: `getdate()` then you don't have to pass it.

Comment: Sorry typo im using MS SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: If you look at the RELATED column on the right of this page you will find numerous questions (and relative answers) to this same question

Comment: Also, a simple google search you will get what you want, first google hit: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15403/Calling-Stored-procedures-in-ADO-NET

Comment: Actually im not returning the date, if i give current date the SP it will generate a number and returns that. It works fine in MS sql server. But i need to get that number from the table by using C#

Comment: @user2742746 - Then add these details in your question with the code you tried in C# and the code of your SP

Comment: I have added by C# code above,My table has two fields one is date and number, im using a logic in my sp to return that number based on the current date

Answer (score 0):

```
Write his code in that method

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("coonectionstring");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Your sp",con);   
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    //input parameters
         cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@currentdate",SqlDbType.DateTime,"currentdate"));
       int i=command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: do i need to return i as integer??returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: its depends,if your method return type is int then you need to return,if it is void the no need to return then simply write command.ExecuteNonQuery(); Here you have only one i/p parameter so you can use command.ExecuteScalar(); also

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use more than one sp in your C# code, I suggest something like this:

```
public static DataTable GetSQLValues(string currentDate)
    {
        SqlParameter[] sqlParams = 
        { 
            new SqlParameter("@currentDate", currentDate)
        };

        return DBHelper.GetTable("MSSQLSPNAME", sqlParams);
    }
```

Use the above for every instance where you need to get table info.

GetTable looks like this:

```
    static SqlConnection _conn;
    static string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["primaryConnStr"]].ToString();
    static SqlCommand _cmd;
    static SqlDataAdapter _dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    public static DataTable GetTable(string sProcName, SqlParameter[] sqlParams)
    {
        using (_conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
        {
            _cmd = new SqlCommand(sProcName, _conn);

            _conn.Open();
            _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (sqlParams != null)
            {
                _cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);
            }

            _dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);

            var results = new DataTable();

            _dataAdapter.Fill(results);
            _conn.Close();

            return results;
        }
    }
```

It will save you a ton of time for each sp call you need from C#.